# What is an actual example of the difference between NSString to NSMutablestring could look like?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I'v been looking around in the questions here and could not find simple example to point me the difference while I was testing some code of my own to test the differentiation.

From what I understand, in an "immutable" string such as 'NSString', I could not preform any 'NSString' methods to modify the string, such as:

```
NSString *s = @"cat";

    s = [NSString stringWithString:@"blamp"];

    NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

But it does work..

Please try to give me and other newbies out there a very  simple example of what won't work and why.
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement :

```
s = [NSString stringWithString:@"blamp"];
```

actually creates a new memory location for the string "blamp" and the old address of `s` gets replaced by this new address.

And you get the feel that the same `s` is updated!!! Actually the pointer now points to some other memory addresss.

---

String manipulation means changing the same string : as if you try

```
NSString *s = @"cat";
[s appendString:@"s"];//tries to append to the same. this will through error.
//the above works with NSMutableString.
```

Comment: so you use mutable strings so you dont have to many object without use in the memory, and instead you create one tht you can play with? @AnnopVaidya

Comment: yes in nsmutablestring , same memory location is used for every PLAY. While in nsstring now memory is allocated.